# How to visually tell the difference between a planetary nebula and a supernova remnant?

Tags: telescope, observational-astronomy, supernova, nebula

If we see a nebula by looking through a powerful telescope, how can we tell whether we are looking at the remnant of a supernova or at a planetary nebula?
Thanks

Comment: This [article](http://www.astronomy.com/magazine/ask-astro/2013/08/planetary-nebulae-and-supernova-remnants) seems to explain it but there is a paywall unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Supernova Remnant contains a Black Hole or a Neutron Star while a Planetary Nebula contains a White Dwarf.

Also, Supernovae Remnants are likely to have great velocities, so Doppler is another plausible choice. - Not through telescope though.